# Unable to view first backup created by Azure for Azure Database for MySQL

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm unable to view the first backup created by Azure for Azure Database for MySQL, a fully managed service by Azure. 
Here is the sequence of steps

1. I'm a subscription owner in Azure and I spin an Azure Database for MySQL Server.
2. I delete the server after 5 hours of creation.
3. I try and create a new server with the same name but this time instead of a blank source. I select backup.

Observation at this time: I am unable to find a backup.

Questions:

1. How long will it take for Azure to create the first automatic backup?
2. If it's within 5 hours of creation for sure then why as a subscription owner I cannot view the backup.
3. Are there some settings to be checked at the time of the creation of the Azure Database for MySQL Server?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

AzureFan

Answer (score 0):

> How long will it take for Azure to create the first automatic backup?

The first full backup is scheduled immediately after a server is created. The initial backup can take longer on a large restored server. The earliest point in time that a new server can be restored to is the time at which the initial full backup is complete.

> If it's within 5 hours of creation for sure then why as a subscription owner I cannot view the backup.

In short, the deleted server is not supported to be restored, so you could not see the backup. If you delete the server, all databases that belong to the server are also deleted and cannot be recovered.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-backup#restore

> Are there some settings to be checked at the time of the creation of the Azure Database for MySQL Server?

For the details of creating the Azure Database for MySQL Server, see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-restore-server-portal